# Grant access to Web API hosted in IIS to connect to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication, asp.net-web-api

Both the SQL Server 2019 Standard edition and the IIS v10 are on the same server, and SQL Server is configured for Windows and SQL Server authentication.

Other applications successfully connect to this SQL Server with Windows AD accounts.

Web API uses this connection string configured in its JSON file:

```
Server=(local);Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

When calling the Web API, it fails, and the following log entry can be seen in the SQL Server log.

> Message:
> Login failed for user 'Domain\ServerName$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

If the standard SQL Server login is used, Web API call work.

```
Server=(local);Database=myDataBase;User Id=sa;Password=sa@123;
```

Can someone help me to setup this with Windows authentication?

Comment: Add the app pool account as a login to SQL Server. If IIS and SQL Server are *not* on the same machine, the app pool should use a domain account

Comment: If IIS is on a different machine and you try to connect using a local account (and IIS APPPOOL\Whatever is local), the connection will be made using the server's computer account, `Domain\ServerName$`.